# Proof about $T^2 = T\circ T$

Tags: linear-transformations

I have the following statement to prove:

> Proof if $T$ is a linear map defined as $T: V\to V$ with $Dim(V)=n$
> and $T^2 = T \circ T=I_V$ with $I_V$ the identity linear map, then $Ker(T-I_V) \cap Ker(T+I_V) = \{0\}$

My attempt was:

If $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are different eigenvalues, then we have that $W_{\lambda_1} \cap W_{\lambda_2} = \{0\}$ and since $W_{\lambda_1}=Ker(T-\lambda_1I_n)$, $W_{\lambda_2}=Ker(T-\lambda_2I_n)$ , this will equivalent to prove that there exists eigenvalues equal to $\lambda_1=1, \lambda_2=-1$.

So i need to prove that there exists at least one $v_1,v_2 \in V$ such that $T(v_1)=v$ and $T(v_2)=-v_2$.

But from here i can't do more.

I tried to find from the information $T(v)\cdot T(v) = T(T(v))$ that $T(v)=v$ but i could not.

Answer (score 1):

In general $\ker(A)\cap \ker(B)\subseteq \ker(B-A)$. Apply this to $A=T-I_V$ and $B=T+I_V$.

Comment: when this not apply?

Comment: Eduardo here A and B are some maps from $X \to Y$. Then what should we expect more? I mean the statement is clear. But although this statement is useful, Jonathan did not use $T^2=I$. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

T is a symetry of V, then $\mu_{T} = X^2-1 = (X-1)(X+1)$. And $(X-1)\wedge (X+1)=1$. By Kernels' lemma, we have : $E= Ker(T-I_{V}) \bigoplus Ker(T+I_{V})$. The conclusion is clear now.